# Django templates sting comprasion every time returns True

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-templates

If I go to the index or annoucements page, I'm sending to the template embed_text with 'index' or 'announcements' page_name respectively. It should set active class to current link in the navbar. [As shown in the picture (movies is my index page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWsEE.png)

It's my code in the index.html template

```
{% if embed_text.page_name == 'index' %}
    {% block movies_active %}active{% endblock %}
{% endif %}
{% if embed_text.page_name == 'announcements' %}
    {% block announcements_active %}active{% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

And it is code in the base.html template that extends to the index.html

```
<li class="{% block movies_active %}{% endblock %}"><a href="{% url 'movies:index' %}"> Movies</a></li>
<li class="{% block announcements_active %}{% endblock %}"><a href="{% url 'movies:announcements' %}"> Announcemets</a></li>
```

So, every time both of expressions return True and set both of links as active, you can see it at the picture. I know, I'm missing a little detail. Please, help resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`block` tag is not affected by `if` tag. You can try this.

```
{% block movies_active %}{% if embed_text.page_name == 'index' %}active{% endif %}{% endblock %}
{% block announcements_active %}{% if embed_text.page_name == 'announcements' %}active{% endif %}{% endblock %}
```